# Using number_with_precision on controller in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to use this helper method on controller. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: On a broader sense, requiring View Helpers in Controller is bad design. But sometimes the system mandates it. So if you post some code on how you intend to use it, it'll be helpful. A quick, but dirty and not recommended way is to use `include ActionView::Helper` in your controller.

Comment: Related if not duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733971/how-do-i-require-numberhelper-and-make-it-work

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Probably not a great idea, but if you must, include the helper like so:

```
class WhateverController
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def show
    render :text => number_with_precision(2342.234, :precision => 2)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 7):

A much better way to control number precision is rails controllers is to use [sprintf](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sprintf)

```
"%.2f" % 2342.234 => "2342.23"
"%.6f" % 2342.234 => "2342.234000"
```

Comment: Why is sprintf better?

Comment: More flexibility than using number_with_precision and doesn't require you to include view helpers in your controller

Comment: It doesn't have a `delimiter:` option.