# How to get number with precision in a controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, actionview

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426315/using-number-with-precision-on-controller-in-rails3).  An answer points out that you can include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper in order to get the number_with_precision method to work in your controllers.  This is also described as a bad practice.  I am working on exporting data to excel which is why I need it my controller (or some non-view file).  Is there a way to get comma delimiters and decimal places on my numbers generated in the controller without having to include the actionview numberhelper?

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Rails 3, you can use `view_context.number_with_precision` to use the view helper from the controller.

Found it here: http://wowkhmer.com/2011/09/09/use-view-helper-methods-in-rails-3-controller/